# Can you give analogy with v-for in Stencil ? (something like v-for in Stencil)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stenciljs

I should copy one part of element few times depends on array in Stencil. I used v-for in Vue, but what can i use in Stencil ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#loops):

> Loops can be created in JSX using either traditional loops when creating JSX trees, or using array operators such as map when inlined in existing JSX.

So

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.items.map((item) =>
        <div>
          <div>{item.name}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

should be about equivalent to

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
  ...
```